# jQuery, next() or prev() or other that don't I know?

Tags: jquery, html

i have this lists, and i want select li element from jquery when the link is click

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="accordion" href="#">1</a></li>    
    <li><a class="accordion" href="#">2</a></li>    
    <li><a class="accordion" href="#">3</a></li>    
    <li><a class="accordion" href="#">4</a></li>    
    <li><a class="accordion" href="#">5</a></li>    
    <li><a class="accordion" href="#">6</a></li>    
</ul>
```

i write this jquery code

```
 $('a.accordion').click(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      div = $('<div/>', {
         id: 'intotheli',
         style: {width:200}
      });
      //console.log(div);

      // loading content  with ajax custom function  
      div.html( loadcontent(div,$(this).attr("href"))); 
      // on this point i want find the li tag that contain the clicked link
      div.slideDown('slow').appendTo($(this));                  

      return false;
});
```

i have tried with .next() and prev() from $(this) but i don't resolve my issue (maybe i used them wrong )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix the title. Same for the question (e.g. what is the "issue"? what is the effect? what did debugging show?)

Comment: in fact i was a bit vague, the issue is i'm not able to target li tag from a tag in jquery code, but the answers have been enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks like you are new to this, here's how I'd rewrite this:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>    
</ul>
```

This makes the markup smaller and tidier.

Then instead of:

```
$('a.accordion').click(function() {
```

I'd use:

```
$('.accordion').on("click", "a", function() {
```

This means only one eventhandler is bound, rather than 6, speeding things up a little, but again just keeping things simple. This change only works with my new markup.

The rest of your code will work as is, `$(this)` still refers to the clicked link.

To get the `li` element that the `a` is in, you use `$(this).parent('li')`.

Answer (score 1):

`.next()` and `.prev()` traverse siblings.  They get the next/previous sibling.  If you want to get the `<li>` from the `<a>`, you want `.parent`.

```
$('a.accordion').click(function() {
    var $li = $(this).parent('li');
});
```